# Can ConfigParser be used to read sections containing column data?

Tags: python, csv, file-io, configparser

I have large input files with the format:

```
[A11N]
#       label     value              error          calculated
         0     1.43262100e+06    2.12071439e+04    1.43261891e+06
         1     3.05578100e+05    2.12071439e+04    3.26592619e+05
         2     3.95689900e+05    2.12071439e+04    3.84788096e+05
         3     4.90816000e+05    2.12071439e+04    4.64785030e+05
         2     5.42676800e+05    2.12071439e+04    5.42395048e+05
[B12N]
#       label     value              error          calculated
         0     1.43262100e+06    2.12071439e+04    1.43261891e+06
         1     3.05578100e+05    2.12071439e+04    3.26592619e+05
         2     3.95689900e+05    2.12071439e+04    3.84788096e+05
         3     4.90816000e+05    2.12071439e+04    4.64785030e+05
         2     5.42676800e+05    2.12071439e+04    5.42395048e+05
[C13N]
#       label     value              error          calculated
         0     1.43262100e+06    2.12071439e+04    1.43261891e+06
         1     3.05578100e+05    2.12071439e+04    3.26592619e+05
         2     3.95689900e+05    2.12071439e+04    3.84788096e+05
         3     4.90816000e+05    2.12071439e+04    4.64785030e+05
         2     5.42676800e+05    2.12071439e+04    5.42395048e+05
```

Note, that the label column will contain repeat values, so I can not simply add an '=' sign in between the 'label' and 'value' columns. I typically read column data like this with 'genfromtxt', but that breaks with the section labels.

Can ConfigParser.read be made to handle such a section? Or would line-by-line handling be the only way to parse the input file?

Comment: I would split this file into chunks by the 'category' (`[A11N]` etc), then process the data with the `csv` library.

Answer (score 0):

First walk over the file, using the 'sections' (`[A11N]` etc) as dictionary keys, then push the remaining lines onto a list as the value.

Once this is done, you can iterate over the dictionary, processing the lists as csv:

```
import csv

csvdata = {}
with open('data.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
  category = ''
  for line in csvfile.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('['):
      category = line
      csvdata[category] = []
    else:
      csvdata[category].append(line)

for cat, row in csvdata.items():
  # Print the section name
  print(cat)
  reader = csv.reader(row, delimiter=' ')
  for data in reader:
    # Print the list of row fields
    print(data)
```